# stargazer left align LaTeX table columns

Tags: r, latex, knitr, stargazer

`stargazer` automatically centres values within tables. **How can I left align the columns?**

Put this code in an .Rnw file and use knitr to convert to .tex:

```
<<load, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE>>=
opts_chunk$set(eval=TRUE, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, dpi=300)
@


\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % Required to insert dummy text

\begin{document}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section{Header}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

<<iris, results = "asis">>=
library(stargazer)
stargazer(iris[1:10,4:5], summary  = FALSE)
@

\end{document}
```

This is the PDF output:

[image]

Comment: Quick and dirty way would be to use regular expression to find the `ccc` string in `\begin{tabular}` and change it to `lcc`.

Comment: Post processing looks like the only way. [The built-in styles don't have alignment capabilities either.](https://github.com/cran/stargazer/blob/da70f63c256937463ba19c9eb5cd3bd9055c3e4c/R/stargazer-internal.R#L217)

Comment: For such straightforward table, why do you insist on using `stargazer`? You might have much more options to fine-tune the LaTeX table with e.g. `xtable`.

Answer (score 4):

As has been pointed out in the comments, you could either post-process the output of stargazer, or use xtable. I'll demonstrate both approaches.

1. **post-processing**: Replace your code chuck with the following two code chunks

   ```
   <<echo=FALSE, results=hide>>=
   library(stargazer)
   tab <- stargazer(iris[1:10,4:5], summary  = FALSE) 
   @

   <<results=tex, echo=FALSE>>=
   collapse <- function(st) paste(st, collapse="")
   st <- gsub(collapse(rep("c", 3)), collapse(rep("l",3)), tab)
   cat(st[4:24])
   @
   ```
2. **xtable**: After installing the `xtable` package, you could use this as your code chuck

   ```
   <<iris, results="asis", echo=FALSE>>=
   library(xtable)
   print(xtable(iris[1:10,4:5], align="lll", caption=""))
   @
   ```

I think the *xtable* approach is probably easier though