# How can I left align latex equations in R Markdown?

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, r-markdown

I'm having some difficulty left aligning equations in R Markdown (i.e. putting the equation on the far left side of page, and aligning subsequent lines). I've generally determined that I want to set the [fleqn] option in the amsmath package to left align all equations, but putting the following in my YAML header gives an error

'Option clash for package amsmath'

```
---
author: "ME"
date: "February 26, 2015"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
output: pdf_document
---
```

A section from my document:

```
$$
\begin{aligned}
Bias(\hat{\theta})  &= E(\hat{\theta}) - \theta \\
                    &= E(2 \bar{X} -1) - \theta \\
                    &= \frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n E(X_i) -1 -\theta \\
                    &= 2E(X) - 1 - \theta \\
                    &= 2 \cdot \frac{\theta+1}{2} - 1 - \theta \\
                    &= 0 \\
\end{aligned}
$$
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks like this was already asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25802590/stargazer-left-align-latex-table-columns

Comment: Not `$` nor `$$`, use `\[`...`\]` instead. See [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)

Comment: Using $ instead of $$ will change some formulas : summation indices will be put right to the summation sign instead of upper and below. So you do this change at the price of "degrading" (in a very strict point of view, that's true) your document.

Answer (score 21):

Try using `$...$` instead of `$$...$$`.

In the case of `$$...$$` in Rmarkdown is center aligned by default

Answer (score 5):

This question has already been asked here: [R Markdown Math Equation Allignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27081054/r-markdown-math-equation-allignment)

The below works for me:

```
$\begin{aligned}
Bias(\hat{\theta})  &= E(\hat{\theta}) - \theta \\
                    &= E(2 \bar{X} -1) - \theta \\
                    &= \frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n E(X_i) -1 -\theta \\
                    &= 2E(X) - 1 - \theta \\
                    &= 2 \cdot \frac{\theta+1}{2} - 1 - \theta \\
                    &= 0 \\
\end{aligned}$
```

Comment: I believe that post only addresses how to align elements of the equation. I believe here they're asking how to align equations to the left of the page. Your code aligns the = symbol for each line, but it will still be centered on the page by default.

Comment: Your answer nor the answers in your link do not help in left aligning equations in R Markdown.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ L(x_{1}, x_{2}, ..., x_{n}| \mu) =  \mu * (1-\mu) $

$log (\ L(x_{1}, x_{2}, ..., x_{n}| \mu)) = h * log(\mu) + (m-h) * log(1-\mu) $

$\frac{\partial  log(\ L(x_{1}, x_{2}, ..., x_{n}| \mu)}{\partial(\mu)}  = \frac{h}{\mu} + \frac{h-m}{1-\mu} $

#### We set this to zero to find the value that maximizes the likelihood 

$\frac{h}{\mu} + \frac{h-m}{1-\mu} = 0 $

$h = m * \mu $

$\mu = \frac{h}{m} $
```

Comment: this does not align the equations at the equals sign anymore